# How to add two SELECT statments together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two separate queries which collect relevant data and count the number of two different services (sms&phone plan, data plan) that telecommunication service offers, both queries are able to get the data from the specified fields, but I wish to do everything using one queries.

```
SELECT a.OperatorName, count(b.planName) as 'Plans'
FROM dbo.Operator a INNER JOIN dbo.Plan b
on a.OperatorID = b.OperatorID
GROUP BY a.OperatorName

SELECT a.OperatorName, count(B.intplanName) as 'Plans'
FROM dbo.Operator AS a
    LEFT JOIN
    InternetPlan as B
    ON a.OperatorID = B.OperatorID
    GROUP BY a.OperatorName
```

Output[First]:

```
OperatorName           | Plans
Verizon                   6
Google                    10
SomethineElse             4
```

Output[Second]:

```
OperatorName           | Plans
Verizon                   2
Google                    9
SomethineElse             9
```

Desired output

```
OperatorName           | Plans
Verizon                   9
Google                    19
SomethineElse             13
```

Both of these queries return the relevant information, the issue starts when I try to combine them.

The below-specified code does not work, I'm unsure as to where it doesn't work properly and why.

```
SELECT a.OperatorName, count(b.planName) as 'Plan'
FROM dbo.Operator AS a
INNER JOIN 
Plan as b
on a.operatorID = b.operatorID
INNER JOIN
InternetPlan as c
on c.operatorID = b.operatorID
GROUP BY a.OperatorName
```

The above query outputs the following:

```
OperatorName           | Plans
Verizon                   12
Google                    90
SomethineElse             36
```

And it should be

```
OperatorName           | Plans
Verizon                   9
Google                    19
SomethineElse             13
```

Comment: SUM(), not count in the first row.

Comment: @jarlh I'm not sure the inner query even compiles.. where is the group by

Comment: I've adjusted the code to explain better what exactly I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem is that you are joining plans to Internet plans, but these are two different entities that are only indirectly related. For an operator with 5 plans and 6 Internet plans, you'll get 5 x 6 = 30 rows in your intermediate result, because you join each of their plans with each of their Internet plans. When aggregating multiple tables, aggregate before joining. After all you want for each operator the plan count and the Internet plan count, so join these counts. Please see my answer on this.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I appreciate your experience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per operator you want to get the plan count and the Internet plan count. So, select from the operator table and join the two counts:

```
select o.operatorname, coalesce(p.cnt, 0) + coalesce(ip.cnt, 0) as plans
from dbo.operator o
left join
(
  select operatorid, count(*) as cnt
  from dbo.plan
  group by operatorid
) p on p.operatorid = o.operatorid
left join
(
  select operatorid, count(*) as cnt
  from internetplan
  group by operatorid
) ip on ip.operatorid = o.operatorid
order by o.operatorname;
```

The same can be achieved with subqueries in the `SELECT` clause or with lateral joins (`OUTER APPLY`).

Comment: Thank you so much, the code which you've sent makes no sense to me (the second day learning SQL), BUT I will use it as a reference to analyze why and what.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the counting from the inner query like so:

```
SELECT tem.Plan, count(Plan) FROM
(
    SELECT a.OperatorName, b.planName as 'Plan'
    FROM dbo.Operator a INNER JOIN dbo.Plan b
    on a.OperatorID = b.OperatorID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.OperatorName, b.intplanName as 'Plan'
    FROM dbo.Operator a INNER JOIN dbo.InternetoPlan b
    on a.OperatorID = b.OperatorID
) AS tem
GROUP BY Plan
ORDER BY Plan
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@sagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69721841/14868997), you could pull `Operator` to the outside of the union, to avoid querying it twice

```sql
SELECT
  o.OperatorName,
  COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Operator o
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT p.OperatorID, p.planName as Plan
    FROM dbo.Plan p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ip.OperatorID, ip.intplanName as Plan
    FROM dbo.InternetoPlan ip
) AS p ON p.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
GROUP BY o.OperatorID, o.OperatorName
ORDER BY o.OperatorName;
```